# Match function returning NA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have been trying to get month name against highest number of bookings but the issue is that two months have same number of bookings and a simple nested `INDEX MATCH` function returns the first month with that number of bookings. I need names for both months in different cells.

**Formula:**

```
=INDEX(AY4:BJ4,1,LARGE(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(AY5:BJ5,LARGE(AY5:BJ5,1),0)),MATCH(COLUMN(AY5:BJ5),COLUMN(AY5:BJ5)),"-"),COLUMNS(BK1:BK1)))
```

**Table:**

[image: Click on the image to view the Table]

Answer (score 0):

Here's the tutorial I followed: https://www.xelplus.com/return-multiple-match-values-in-excel/

I have tried to recreated your situation below:

[image: Pic of how I've set it up]

[image: Formula and output]

The formula is: `=IFERROR(INDEX($AY$4:$BJ$4,1,AGGREGATE(15,3,(MAX($AY$5:$BJ$5)=$AY$5:$BJ$5)/(MAX($AY$5:$BJ$5)=$AY$5:$BJ$5)*COLUMN($AY$5:$BJ$5)-COLUMN($AX$5),COLUMNS($AY$5:AY5))),"BLANK")`

The formula should be entered from column AY to BJ, and all the cases with the highest numbers will show up in one single row. I recommend recreating the solution using that website, it definitely helped a lot.

Comment: Hey @PuravTheGreat, yes this is really useful. One more question, what if I have to get the month name against the top 5 months? For example, in this case, how can it return me " April, November, January, February"? Is it possible to get them in the descending order?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I'd recommend going to the website I've linked as it might have what you need. I personally would probably use VBA for that. Also, if you the solution helped you I'd love it if you could vote for it as the best answer!